# Problems with mysql_fetch_array

Tags: php, mysql

So i'm having trouble using mysql_fetch_array. this is my code:

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE group='$group'");
$query=mysql_fetch_array($sql);
```

i am getting the following error:

```
Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource
```

Any help would be very appricated

Comment: since it's obvious that you're just learning PHP, let me save you a lot of time and tell you now that the `mysql_xxx()` functions are deprecated. If you're learning them now, you are learning obsolete techniques. You should consider learning up-to-date PHP techniques instead; eg the PDO library. Here's a tutorial to get you started: http://phpmaster.com/avoid-the-original-mysql-extension-2/

Comment: When developing code, include error reporting like PHP's (now deprecated) mysql_error() function. It makes things a whole lot easier to debug.

Comment: @Strawberry Thanks. i'll use php's mysql_error() function from now on ;) I forgot it existed, lol

Comment: If you're the one who created this schema, avoid creating columns or tables that are [reserved keywords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) like `GROUP`. It's really annoying to have to deal with these sorts of names as special cases all the time.

Comment: You must be especially careful to [properly escape all values](http://bobby-tables.com/php) when composing queries to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). The `$group` value here is not obviously escaped and could be a huge liability. If you use PDO and are disciplined about using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) you won't have these sorts of issues.

Comment: @wesker Good. Now that you've forgotten, you can use its modern, safer, equivalents instead!

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

group is a mysql function, you must enclose it with ` so mysql know that it's a name and not the function. like this:

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE `group`='$group'");
$query=mysql_fetch_array($sql);
```

Comment: Wow, that just did it. Thank you very much! Been working around with this in like 2 days. Thank you very much

Comment: Why i couldn't see any difference between this answer and question? Is this question modified?

Comment: @Eray Yea, i just copy-pasted his code, and forgot to modify it. thanks for the comment

Comment: @Eray - the field name `group` has had backticks added to it. It is a MySQL keyword, so it was causing the query to fail, and thus `$sql` was `false` instead of a recordset, so the fetch function blew up. Some basic error checking would have been a good idea to help spot this kind of thing.

Comment: @Spudley thanks for assist. ahmad albayati got my problem. he forgot to modify it. :)